# HTTP Digest/Basic Auth with Python Requests module

Tags: xml, http, python-3.x, python-requests, digest-authentication

My goal here is to be able to parse `html/xml data` from a password protected page then based on that data (a timestamp) I need to send `xml commands` to another device. The page I am trying to access is a webserver generated by an IP device.
Also, if this would be easier to accomplish in another language please let me know.
I have very little experience programming (one C programming class)

I have tried using Requests for Basic and Digest Auth. I still can't get authenticated, which is stopping me from getting any further.

Here are my attempts:

```
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPDigestAuth

url='http://myUsername:myPassword@example.com/cgi/metadata.cgi?template=html'
r = requests.get(url, auth=HTTPDigestAuth('myUsername', 'myPassword'))        
r.status_code

print(r.headers) 
print(r.status_code)
```

Output:

```
401 
CaseInsensitiveDict({'Content-Length': '0', 'WWW-Authenticate': 'Digest realm="the realm of device", nonce="23cde09025c589f05f153b81306928c8", qop="auth"', 'Server': 'Device server name'})
```

I have also tried `BasicAuth` with Requests and get the same output. I have tried both including the `user:pass@` within the url and not. Although when I put that input that into my browser it works.

I thought that requests handled header data for `Digest/BasicAuth` but maybe I need to include headers also?

I used Live HTTP Headers(firefox) and got this:

```
GET /cgi/metadata.cgi?template=html
HTTP/1.1 
Host: [Device IP] 
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:28.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/28.0 Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,/;q=0.8 Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5 
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate DNT: 1 Connection: keep-alive
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized WWW-Authenticate: Digest realm="Device Realm", nonce="a2333eec4cce86f78016343c48382d21", 
qop="auth" 
Server: Device Server Content-Length: 0
```

Comment: Are you sure that your code contains **two** `request.get()` (the second doesn't send any auth info)? Provide the code that you've actually tried (you could replace device ip with `example.com`, change user/pass using the equivalent symbol set (if your password uses space then include it, if it has `"` in it then include the quote, etc).

Comment: This is the exact code I have tried(except for the spaces inbetween "digest- and auth in the url, formatting got messed up when I copied it over. I have tried with and without the end part of the url as well (digest-auth/auth/user/pass/) I only included that because that is what is shown in the example in the Requests documentation, also have replace both /user/pass/ with actual credentials, I figure I am missing a step? Does this need to be a .post instead of get, I have tried that too to no avail.

Answer (score 9):

The two requests are independent:

```
r = requests.get(url, auth=HTTPDigestAuth('user', 'pass')) 
response = requests.get(url) #XXX <-- DROP IT
```

The second request does not send any credentials. Therefore it is not surprising that it receives `401 Unauthorized` http response status.

To fix it:

1. Use the same `url` as you use in your browser. Drop `digest-auth/auth/user/pass` at the end. It is just an example in the requests docs
2. Print `r.status_code` instead of `response.status_code` to see whether it's succeeded.

---

Why would you use username/password in the url and in `auth` parameter? Drop username/password from the url. To see the request that is sent and the response headers, you could [enable logging/debugging](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/api/#api-changes):

```
import logging
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPDigestAuth

# these two lines enable debugging at httplib level (requests->urllib3->httplib)
# you will see the REQUEST, including HEADERS and DATA, 
# and RESPONSE with HEADERS but without DATA.
# the only thing missing will be the response.body which is not logged.
try:
    import httplib
except ImportError:
    import http.client as httplib

httplib.HTTPConnection.debuglevel = 1

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG) # you need to initialize logging, 
                      # otherwise you will not see anything from requests

# make request
url = 'https://example.com/cgi/metadata.cgi?template=html'
r = requests.get(url, auth=HTTPDigestAuth('myUsername', 'myPassword'),
                 timeout=10)
print(r.status_code)
print(r.headers)
```

Comment: I got rid of the second request and the extra at the end of the url. Now when I run the code, It seems like its just running in shell indefinitely it never gets to the `print()` lines. I have updated the code to show what I am trying now. I have tried with and without `user:pass@` again as well.

Comment: if it is stuck then enable logging to see where it is stuck

Answer (score 4):

```
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPDigestAuth

url='https://example.com/cgi/metadata.cgi?template=html'
r = requests.get(url, auth=HTTPDigestAuth('myUsername', 'myPassword'), verify=False,  stream=True)        


print(r.headers) 
print(r.status_code)
```

fixed with adding `stream=True` since the page is streaming xml/html data. My next questions is, how do I store/parse a constant stream of data?

I tried storing in r.content but it seems to run indefinitely (the same problem I had before)

Comment: nice simple example.