# Download text data from HTML link in Python

Tags: python, pandas, url, https

Hi I want to download delimited text which is hosted on a HTML Link. (The link is accessible on a Private network only, so can't share here).

In R, following function solves the purpose (all other functions gave "Unauthorized access" or "401" error)

```
url = 'https://dw-results.ansms.com/dw-platform/servlet/results? job_id=13802737&encoding=UTF8&mimeType=plain'
download.file(url, "~/insights_dashboard/testing_file.tsv")
a = read.csv("~/insights_dashboard/testing_file.tsv",header = T,stringsAsFactors = F,sep='\t')
```

I want to do the same thing in Python, for which I used:

(A)urllib and requests.get()

```
import urllib.request

url_get = requests.get(url, verify=False)
urllib.request.urlretrieve(url_get, 'C:\\Users\\cssaxena\\Desktop\\24.tsv')
```

(B)requests.get() and read.html

```
url='https://dw-results.ansms.com/dw-platform/servlet/results? job_id=13802737&encoding=UTF8&mimeType=plain'
s = requests.get(url, verify=False)
a = pd.read_html(io.StringIO(s.decode('utf-8')))
```

(C) Using wget:

```
import wget
url = 'https://dw-results.ansms.com/dw-platform/servlet/results? job_id=13802737&encoding=UTF8&mimeType=plain'  
wget.download(url,--auth-no-challenge, 'C:\\Users\\cssaxena\\Desktop\\24.tsv')
```

OR

```
wget --server-response -owget.log "https://dw-results.ansms.com/dw-platform/servlet/results? job_id=13802737&encoding=UTF8&mimeType=plain"
```

NOTE: The URL doesn't asks for any credentials and it is accessible by browser and able to download using R with download.file. I am looking for a solution in Python

Comment: Can you check `download.file.method` in R, please?

Comment: I am looking for a method in Python.  download.file works well in R

Comment: Understood but there is an environment variable in R called `dowload.file.method` in order to help I need to know its value.

Comment: following 1 line code does it all :

 
download.file(url, "C:/user/insights_dashboard/testing_file.tsv")

Comment: Yes but `download.file` has a parameter 'method' which defaults to the value of the environment variable I mentioned in my two previous comments. I need to know its value in order to help further.

Comment: try enabling debug log level to see whats happening https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23254013/http-digest-basic-auth-with-python-requests-module

Answer (score 0):

```
def geturls(path):
    yy=open(path,'rb').read()
    yy="".join(str(yy))
    yy=yy.split('<a')

    out=[]
    for d in yy:
        z=d.find('href="')
        if z>-1:
            x=d[z+6:len(d)]
            r=x.find('"')
            x=x[:r]
            x=x.strip(' ./')
                 #
            if (len(x)>2) and (x.find(";")==-1):
                out.append(x.strip(" /"))
    out=set(out)
    return(out)

pg="./test.html"# your html

url=geturls(pg)

print(url)
```